# IDA cannot launch debugger for 64-bit exe files

Tags: ida, x86-64

I want to launch IDA debugger for one 64-bit exe file and it fails, have tried with more samples, but result always the same.

Here is that I do.

1. Launch `IDA Pro (64-bit)`
2. Select `Debugger` -> `Run` -> `Local Windows Debugger` from top menu.
3. Select my file. [image: How it looks] and click `OK`.
4. At this point getting such prompt. [image: prompt] and click `Yes`.
5. Finally got such error: [image: error1]
6. And after that this-one: [image: error2]

It happens all the time, have tried it on a few different VMs on my actual machine. I'm using full version of IDA v6.7.141229.

I believe something has to be configured, as the last error says something about wrong parameters, can someone advice?

Comment: I can't check this right now, but i think i remember that, for 64 bit programs, you have to start the 64 bit remote debugger and connect to that instead of debugging the file directly. So, "Run -> local windows debugger" is wrong. Start the win64_remotex64 server manually, then have IDA connect to it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since IDA is a 32 bit process, it can only debug x64 binaries remotely ([source](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/debugger/)).

To do that, you need to use the `IDA X.X/dbgsrv/win64_remotex64.exe` file and start a debugger. Once the debugger is running, you can connect to it "remotely" and debug. You can check [this tutorial](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/debugger/cross-win-linux/win32towin64.shtml) for more specific details.

Comment: The only thing that is also required is running IDA as administrator, otherwise it doesn't work, no matter if debugged program requires elevation or not.

Comment: What's also important to note is that the password for `win64_remotex64` must be specified without any spaces after `-P`. I know, it's a very strange way of doing it. And also on the client machine make sure to start a 64-bit version of IDA. Also as administrator.

Comment: If you are getting socket error make sure firewall doesn't block the connection and/or port is not already used. In my case I got an error and had to disable COMODO firewall entirely

Answer (score 8):

I write this mostly for myself as I'm tired of going thru this over and over again. Here's how you can debug x64 processes on a local machine with IDA Pro:

(1) Create a .bat file with the following:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\IDA 6.5\dbgsrv\win64_remotex64" -Pnh8sy261
```

in this case it's the location of `win64_remotex64` or remote debugger and `nh8sy261` is just some random password. You pick it. Make sure though not to put any spaces after the `-P` parameter and the password.

(2) Run batch file from (1) as admin.

(3) Open 64-bit version of IDA Pro as admin. (File `"C:\Program Files (x86)\IDA 6.5\idaq64.exe"`)

(4) Pick `Go` to work on your own. Then in the blank IDA Pro window, in the menu go to `Debugger -> Run -> Remote Windows debugger`. Then in the `Application` pick your application with the `...` button. Specify debuggee parameters and directory, if needed. Then in the `Hostname` add `127.0.0.1`, port as `23946` and password as what you typed above in the batch file:

[image]

You can also check to `Save network settings as default` for later access. Then click OK.

(5) At this point the debugger should load the `debuggee` process and you should be able to step through it.